# Center Div inside another (100% width) div

Tags: css, xhtml

Quite a "simple" problem here and not sure why it's being so complicated.

1. Have a 100% (width) sized div.
2. Have another div positioned in the middle of this div (sized 940px width)

Any ideas? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to center DIV in DIV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-center-div-in-div)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
.parent { text-align: center; }
.parent > .child { margin: 0 auto; width: 900px; }
```

Comment: I was missing the text-align it seems as i had the margin and wasn't working.  Accepted, cheers.

Comment: text-align:center does not help with centering the inner div.

Comment: centers the stuff (text) inside though, resulting in the same desired outcome (if you only have text). for auto-margin to work, you also need a width on the inner div.

Comment: Read [this explanation](http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center1.html) about centering one div in another with `text-align`. According to this explanation, `text-align` is not supposed to apply to divs, but it does e.g. in IE5 where, coincidentally, `margin` does not work properly. So this is a workaround; and as a side effect, it also centers the text inside the inner div.

Comment: Don't know why this eluded me.  Specifying the width is all it took.

Answer (score 32):

The below style to the inner div will center it.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 21):

for detail info, let's say the code below will make a div aligned center:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

or simply use:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

but bear in mind, the above CSS code only works when you specify a fixed width (not 100%) on your html element. so the complete solution for your issue would be:

```
.your-inner-div {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 900px;
}
```

Comment: This is a great example because you correctly explicitly point out that a width on the inner div is required.

Answer (score 6):

The key is the **margin: 0 auto;** on the inner div.  A proof-of-concept example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<body>
    <div style="background-color: blue; width: 100%;">
        <div style="background-color: yellow; width: 940px; margin: 0 auto;">
            Test
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good answer as it's crucial to have the right doc type if you're using the margin: 0 auto technique

Answer (score 5):

```
.outerdiv {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: table;
}
```

Doesn't work in internet explorer 7... but who cares ?

Answer (score 4):

Just add `margin: 0 auto;` to the inside div.