# CSS difficulty horizontally displaying / repeating left and right wrapper images to ends of screen

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting my left and right repeaters to fill the available space left on wide screens for a website I am working on. The left and right repeaters are background images (approxamately 350px wide) that I would like to show part of, or even repeat if the screen (visible area of screen shown in red) becomes wide enough.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

John

[plan of website http://tmw.isystems.co.nz/website.png](http://tmw.isystems.co.nz/website.png)

Comment: Just to finish this off, Brocks solution worked to get my repeaters repeating and I found a solution for centering at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423651/center-div-inside-another-100-width-div

All my issues solved. Thanks guys!

Comment: You're welcome.  If the issue is solved, please mark the question as answered (click the check-mark next to the best answer).  This helps everybody and increases the odds that any future questions are answered.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the float on ids: `right_wrap_container` and `right_repeater`.

(Based on: http://tmw.isystems.co.nz/ as served at 16:25, New Zealand time.)

Comment: Thanks, this worked a treat. I'm not sure how to pull off centering the page now that the repeat is happening but I'm sure I'll get it working in the end.

Comment: The current page looks centered, to me.  Guess you figured it out.  Is this question answered?

Comment: yeah there was a posting on the margin: 0 auto; technique elsewhere on stackoverflow that I used. Thanks for your help! Slowly getting my head around this CSS thing... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your widths should be set to percentages.

Comment: yes sure, http://tmw.isystems.co.nz

There are still a few hairy bits (search sits in the wrong place), content missing etc but I can fix those myself. Thanks for asking!

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try the percentages thing. I'm not sure how I'll get around having fixed width images with percentages but I'll have a play and a google and get back to you

Comment: The percentages apply to the width of the containers, but not images. You're using js to inject your innerHTMLs, which is preventing people from taking a look at your source without a live DOM viewer, thus not being able to fully help.

Comment: Thanks Babiker. However I don't think percentages work in my situation as I have a fixed width header that needs to marry up with my left and right wrappers to get the look right. If I set a percentage, then the wrappers don't necessarily sit flush against the header (depending on the width of the screen). I had the thought that I could split my header image, set a background colour, and float the header parts left and right respectively, with the background color filling in the middle, but before I try this I'm hoping to find another way around centering the page.

Answer (score 0):

to elaborate more on babikers response:

assuming your repeaters are different images (if they aren't this becomes trivial)

There's a few ways off the top of my head (untested):

- left div width 50% or body -- background has left repeater
- right div width 50% -- background right repeater
- absolute position, z-index up the content on top of it
- body -- background has left repeater, position relative (maybe optional?)
- wrapper div has no width -- background right repeater -- position relative (to body) left 50%
- inner wrapper position absolute left (or margin left) -1/2 width of content (e.g. 480px for a 960px layout)
- use display: table... or use tables lol