# Best way/s to position d3 visualizations without an iframe?

Tags: d3.js

[All the examples](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) I've looked at on d3js.org use an iframe to position the visualization top and center on the page.

When I've tried embedding a visualization on the page directly, without using an iframe, it drops to the bottom left of the page, under all other page elements.

Anyone know any good alternatives for positioning besides using an iframe?

Answer (score 2):

Use a DIV. That's what I do. You can see an example of this [here](http://blog.stephenboak.com/2011/08/07/easy-as-a-pie.html) -

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS for this:

```
svg{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:0px;
}
```

This example will position it at the bottom half of the screen, aligned left.  Width is defined in d3 when setting height and width of SVG, like so:

```
var width = $(window).width();
var height = $(window).height()/2;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Obviously (maybe not), you don't need to use jQuery to get the width and height of the window.  Repurpose as needed.  The point is the CSS bit.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to diagnose without seeing it.... Are you using SVG? If so, could it be that your `<svg>` tag is missing a `display:block`?

More in general:

The div that frames the visualization –– the one that has a width less than the page's width –– should have a `margin: 0 auto` to center it within its parent element. [A bit more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423651/center-div-inside-another-100-width-div).

Comment: Thanks, the examples are the d3.js gallery page:  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery  View source on any of those and you'll the actual vis is contained in an iframe.

Comment: @Kurtosis I meant it's hard to diagnose without seeing YOUR example; of embedding YOUR visualization without an iFrame.

Comment: Ah, sorry, not up on the web yet, still in dev.  Will see what I can do.